# Send $_GET vars on click link - PHP & Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to autoupdate page using PHP and Ajax. Right now I have this code on a page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="Page-Like.php?idSub=12&idCat=32" class="post"><i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></a>
</body>
</html>
```

When the user clicks on the link it is redirected to another page called "Page-Like.php"

```
include("config.php");

//get vars
$idSubliminal=$_GET["idSubliminal"];
$idCategoria=$_GET["idCategoria"];

// mysql_query("insert into Rating .... (mysql insert query)


echo "<script>
location.href=\"AudioSubliminal.php?idSubliminal=$idSubliminal&idCategoria=$idCategoria\";
</script>";
```

What I want is to do this usig Ajax in order to not refresh the page. I know I'm missing the javascript code, but I would like to get some suggestions to complete this script.

Thanks!

Comment: You should not be using mysql_* functions which are deprecated in PHP7 and you code is open to sql injection. Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a basic ajax request to achieve your functionality. check the sample request below.

```
  function ajaxpr(){
        var URLString="idSub=12&idCat=32"; 
        ajax_request = $.ajax({
               type: 'GET',
               url: "Page-Like.php",
               data: URLString,
               dataType : 'html',
               context: $(this),
               success: function (msg) 
               {
                    //perform the required operation after success
                });

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

add function onclick on tag . then define that function using :

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: {idSub: "12", idCat: "32"},
        url: "Page-Like.php",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            //DEFINE FUNCTION HERE
        }
    });
```

This is using ajax function without refresh page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use many methods to implement Ajax on you're code.

One of this is [jQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_ajax), other is [mootools](http://demos111.mootools.net/Ajax), etc.. Depends of wich library you know or want to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Using ajax to load a page is easy. Follow this link http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

```
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
     // Change this to your desired DOM tag
     document.body.innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "Page-Like.php?idSub=12&idCat=32", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Now it's just a matter of putting event listener to run loadDoc() function. If the link is dynamic, you can parse the parameter to the function.

However, I notice you have a js script inside your php which will redirect again to AudioSubliminal.php. If this is your desired flow then it's okay. If not, you can create another function

```
function loadAudioSubliminal(idSub, idCat) {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
         // Change this to your desired DOM tag
         document.body.innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;

        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "AudioSubliminal.php?idSubliminal=" + idSub + "&idCategoria=" + idCat, true);
      xhttp.send();
    }
```

and modified loadDoc() to receive a parameter such that idSub and idCat can be passed again. for Example :

```
function loadDoc(idSub, idCat) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
       // Change this to your desired DOM tag
       document.body.innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;

       // run the function after finished loading Page-like.php
       loadAudioSubliminal(idSub, idCat)
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", "Page-Like.php?idSub=" + idSub + "&idCat=" + idCat, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```